# Character encoding issue in my website

Tags: html, character-encoding

Live site- http://www.mzuri.co.mz/signage.php

This page contains Portugage language, a lot of Character disappear on that page.
There are a lot of symbols when it goes to portuguese translation (eg: Ã³s fazemos os serviÃ§os)..

Real word- "Sinalização" but on my website is show "SinalizaÃ§Ã£o".

Any idea how to fix that issue.

Comment: Some are working, some aren't. What's the difference between them? Where does the different content come from? Give us something to work with here.

Comment: Right from your HTML: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 solves most of the encoding issues.

» Change the file to be "UTF-8 encoding".

» Add line at the top of the webpage.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

» Use this conversion in PHP code:

```
$new_str = mb_convert_encoding($original_str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have put Portuguese characters using ASCII with the Portuguese code page 860, then you need to put that as your code page. The other solution is to load the Portuguese text in a text editor specifying 860 code page, then save the text as UTF-8. You can then specify UTF-8 as your encoding in your web page.